# Port warning when chain starts with Gain in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I was starting out with Simulink yesterday. Here's what I did: I connected a Gain to an Integrator, then to a Zero-Order Hold, then to a Workspace. I made the gain k*u, where k is a scalar I define my workspace. So the first element in the chain is the gain. Is that ok?

The problem is, when I run the program I get the warning: Warning: Input port 1 of 'test_simulink/Gain' is not connected.

Why is there a warning? Do I need to worry about it?
From what I understand, ports are used when subsystems need to take input/give output to/form larger systems. So in this situation, a port seems unecessary.

So why the warning?

Answer (score 0):

You need a source of data which produces the values and tells the rest of the blocks down the chain what kind of data it is, what is the size, whether it is complex and what is the sample time etc. The source can be any block which does not have inputs. You can find many such blocks in the Simulink sources library. An input port block used at the top level is a kind of source. Refer to the documentation for input port block for specifying data inputs to the model. So a first block that is not connected is not ok. Try using blocks like "constant" or "sine wave" from sources library if you are just trying out.

Without the source the rest of the blocks in the chain will assume some kind of default data type, sizes and complexity for their inputs. This is usually double precision, scalar, real data. When running the model you would be getting values as 0. It is a good practice to connect all the ports in the model so that all the data types are completely specified.

One situation where you may not be using sources is a feedback loop which feeds its own data as input and uses initial conditions to start the loop.

Comment: So I should an input block that has a port? And where should I connect that port?

Comment: You should add a block that has an output port and connect that to the Gain. For example, drag a sine wave block into the model and connect its single output port to the input port of Gain. Also check out the many example models that are linked through the documentation.